# How to animate scroll position to target element in scrollable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I scroll to multiple anchors in a scrollable `dviv`?. My code is not working properly. I checked it's working fine when I take reference the `html` and `body` elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btnpins a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.results').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 60
    }, 400);
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.results {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btnpins">
  <a href="#result1">Pin 1</a>
  <a href="#result2">Pin 2</a>
  <a href="#result3">Pin 3</a>
  <a href="#result4" class="focus">Pin 4</a>
</div>

<div class="results">
  <div class="resultin" id="result1">
    <h5>Result 1</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="resultin" id="result2">
    <h5>Result 2</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="resultin" id="result3">
    <h5>Result 3</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="resultin" id="result4">
    <h5>Result 4</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be scrolling relative to the parent container, which in your case is `.results`. Use `$('.results').scrollTop()` to get the container position and add it to your `scrollTop` position calculation

```
$('.results').stop().animate({
  scrollTop: $('.results').scrollTop() + $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 60
}, 400);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btnpins a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.results').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: $('.results').scrollTop() + $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 60
    }, 400);
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.results {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btnpins">
  <a href="#result1">Pin 1</a>
  <a href="#result2">Pin 2</a>
  <a href="#result3">Pin 3</a>
  <a href="#result4" class="focus">Pin 4</a>
</div>

<div class="results">
  <div class="resultin" id="result1">
    <h5>Result 1</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="resultin" id="result2">
    <h5>Result 2</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="resultin" id="result3">
    <h5>Result 3</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="resultin" id="result4">
    <h5>Result 4</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because `offset()` returns the position of the element relative to the `document`, not the parent container, hence the value returned is thrown out when the scroll position of `.results` is not at the top.

To address this you need to allow for the `offset()` and `scrollTop()` of the `.results` div in the position calculation. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.btnpins a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let $results = $('.results');
    let $target = $($(this).attr('href'));
    
    $results.stop().animate({
     scrollTop: $target.offset().top - $results.offset().top + $results.scrollTop()
    }, 400);
  });
});
```

```css
.results {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btnpins">
  <a href="#result1">Pin 1</a>
  <a href="#result2">Pin 2</a>
  <a href="#result3">Pin 3</a>
  <a href="#result4" class="focus">Pin 4</a>
</div>

<div class="results">
  <div class="resultin" id="result1">
    <h5>Result 1</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="resultin" id="result2">
    <h5>Result 2</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="resultin" id="result3">
    <h5>Result 3</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="resultin" id="result4">
    <h5>Result 4</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```